# Marionette's CompositeView event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I'm having trouble using Marionette's CompositeView. I render my model in my CompositeView using a template and want to add a click event to it. Somehow I can't get the events to work using the `events: { "click": "function" }` handler on the CompositeView... What am I doing wrong?

```
var FactsMenuItem = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: tmpl['factsmenuitem'],

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('factsmenuitem');
    },

    onRender: function() {
        console.log('factsmenuitem');
    }

});

var FactsMenuView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: tmpl['factsmenu'],

    itemView: FactsMenuItem,

    itemViewContainer: ".subs",

    events: {
        'click': 'blaat'
    },

    blaat: function() {
        console.log('this is not working');
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.get('pages').on('sync', function () {
            this.collection = this.model.get('pages');
            this.render();
        }, this);
    },

    onRender: function() {
        console.log('render factsmenu');
    }

});


var FactsLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

    template: tmpl['facts'],

    regions: {
        pages: ".pages",
        filter: ".filter",
        data: ".data"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.currentPage = {};

        this.factsMenu = new FactsMenu();
        this.factsView = new FactsMenuView({model: this.factsMenu});
    },

    onRender: function() {
        this.pages.show(this.factsView);
    }

});
```

**Edit:**
I removed some code that made the question unclear...

The problem lies that the events of the non-collectionview of the compositeview (the modelView??) are not fired. I think this has something to do with the way the FactsLayoutView instantiates the compositeview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the way the region was rendered. In my FactsLayout is used this code:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.currentPage = {};

    this.factsMenu = new FactsMenu();
    this.factsView = new FactsMenuView({model: this.factsMenu});
},

onRender: function() {
    this.pages.show(this.factsView);
}
```

Apparently you can't show a view on a onRender function... I had to change the way the FactsLayout is initialized:

```
var layout = new FactsLayout({
    slug: slug
});
layout.render();

var factsMenu = new FactsMenu({ slug: slug });
var factsView = new FactsMenuView({model: factsMenu});

layout.pages.show(factsView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand your question well but if you need to listen an event fired from an item view within your composite view you should do like the following.

Within the item view `test` method.

```
this.trigger("test");
```

Within the composite view `initialize` method.

```
this.on("itemview:test", function() { });
```

Note that when an event is fired from an item of a `CollectionView` (a `CompositeView` is a `CollectionView`), it is prepended by `itemview` prefix.

Hope it helps.

Edit: Reading you question another time, I think this is not the correct answer but, about your question, I guess the click in the composite view is captured by the item view. Could you explain better your goal?

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear... The question wasn't about the events in the item views (those are working...), it's about the events on the CompositeView (in the factsmenu template...)

Comment: @thomasjonas Could post some details about your template? Thanks

Comment: terribly sorry for the ridiculously late reply. Turns out it had something to do the way the pages region is rendered/shown (see my answer).

Comment: can you please tell how can I get model for the itemview on which test event is occured?

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil Please open a new question and add the reference here. Thanks.